# How do I animate a widget like the battery widget by elvison

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation

I have been searching for how to create an animated widget. I have found a number of examples that dont seem to work properly and several post that say it should not be done. I tried the frame animation from [this](http://animated-widget-for-hpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ExampleAnimatedWidget/res/) sample unsuccefully but I was able to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063257/battery-widget-in-android) type of animation to work with very very poor results and I had to turn off my phone.

I was going to give up but I figured I would download some other animated widgets to see if they run continuously or just on an event. I found that the battery widget by elvison runs while plugged in but I did not notice any performance issues.

I guess I would need to compromise and have mine animated while plugged in but maybe also run through a cycle when clicked or when updated.

Can someone explain how the battery widget animation is accomplished or how I should go about doing this in my app? Is there a working and well explained sample somewhere or can someone point me in the right direction of where to start?

Thanks,
--Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching around and testing other solutions, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565023/is-there-a-way-to-animate-on-a-home-widget) post which mentioned using the progress bar for animation. I didn't realize that progress bars could be customized but using one works perfectly. I will be testing the impact on resources leaving it animated vs. A short animation on an event.